# Retrieving file name of a specify folder in isolated storage windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to retrieve all the file name under "ScheduleFolder" and place it into a listbox.
How should i go about doing it?
How to let it show into the scheduleListBox?

```
       IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
       string[] fileNames = myStore.GetFileNames("./ScheduleFolder/*.*");

        foreach (string name1 in fileNames)
        {
           yo = fileNames[0];
        }
        scheduleListBox.Items.Add(yo);
        textBlock1.Text = yo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
string[] fileNames = isf.GetFileNames("./DirectoryName/*.*");
```

Comment: I tried it works. But how to put it into the listbox such that it will show all the various file name in it.

Comment: foreach (var name in fileNames) { 
      ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
      item.Content = name;
      lstNames.Items.Add(item);

}

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably use this...

```
IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
string[] fileNames = myStore.GetFileNames("./ScheduleFolder/*.*");
scheduleListBox.ItemsSource = fileNames;
```